# I want to set local storage in my React application using useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Here is my React application code. How can I resolve this? Method I use is slightly correct but I don't know how to use these in `localStorage()`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import trashIcon from './trash.svg';

function App() {
  const [taskInput, updateTaskInput] = useState('');
  const [toDolist, updateToDoList] = useState([]);

  const inputKeyDown = (event) => {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) addNote();
  };
  const addNote = () => {
    toDolist.push({ description: taskInput, isComplete: false });
    updateToDoList(toDolist);
    updateTaskInput('');
  };

  //adding datas in local storage session

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('lists', JSON.stringify(toDolist));
  }, [toDolist]);

  return (
    <div className='app-background'>
      <p className=' heading-text'> To do List</p>
      <div className='task-container'>
        <div>
          <input
            className='text-input'
            value={taskInput}
            onKeyDown={inputKeyDown}
            onChange={(event) => updateTaskInput(event.target.value)}
          />
          <button className='add-button' onClick={addNote}>
            ADD
          </button>
        </div>
        {toDolist?.length ? (
          toDolist.map((toDoObject, index) => (
            <ListItem
              index={index}
              itemData={toDoObject}
              deleteTask={deleteTask}
              mark={mark}
            />
          ))
        ) : (
          <p className='no-item-text'> No Task added</p>
        )}
      </div>

      <p className='footer-text'>Sabar_I ❤️</p>
    </div>
  );
}

function ListItem(props) {
  return (
    <div className='list-item row jc-space-between'>
      <span
        className={props.itemData.isComplete ? 'task-complete' : ''}
        onClick={() => props.mark(props.index)}
      >
        {props.itemData.isComplete ? `✅ ` : ''}&nbsp;
        {props.itemData?.description}
      </span>
      <img
        src={trashIcon}
        className='delete-icon'
        onClick={() => props.deleteTask(props.index)}
        alt='/'
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to update the `lists` key every time the `toDoList` is updated you should do it in the `addNote` method.
Also, you should change the way you call the `updateToDoList` hook:

```
  const addNote = () => {
    const newNote = { description: taskInput, isComplete: false };
    updateToDoList((oldToDoList) => [...oldToDoList, newNote]);
    updateTaskInput('');

    // Update localStorage with the updated list 
    localStorage.setItem('lists', JSON.stringify(toDolist));
  };
```